# Sign in with Apple: verify token at server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, apple-sign-in

Hi I am trying to verify the apple auth credentials provided by the client-side application,  on the server-side, I am getting these fields from the client: `authorizationCode`, `identityToken` along with a lot of other fields.

I've tried reading a lot of blogs but none of them exactly mentions these fields. what is the easiest way to verify and get user details by using these fields to some apple API

I've done that for Google, where the client passes the access token to backend and using `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=YourToken` we can verify the token and get user details.

Please suggest some similar way for apple. Thanks.
I am using ROR, in case that helps.

Comment: i think we have the same problem May you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472517/how-to-validate-an-id-token-signature-with-apple-as-an-alternative-to-google-oau

Comment: Can you write a php script which do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I was able to figure out how to verify the access token received from the client-side.
Apple does not provide any API for validating access-token, I highly recommend [this blog](https://sarunw.com/posts/sign-in-with-apple-3/#what-to-validate) It explains the whole Process quite neatly.
[This is the ruby code link for the same](https://gist.github.com/styrken/78ca9e32e1227620700d5d2749458704).

Comment: I ran into some problems with the ruby code above -- there are 2 keys supplied in the certificate and only one of them works sometimes. So I need to check both.

Comment: The JWT token expires after 5 minutes, so you need to be quick enough.

Answer (score 2):

For those who need React-Native client code for this, see below:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as AppleAuthentication from 'expo-apple-authentication';
import { signInWithApple } from '../api';

const AppleAuthenticationButton = () => (
  <AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButton
    buttonType={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonType.SIGN_IN}
    buttonStyle={AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationButtonStyle.WHITE}
    cornerRadius={5}
    style={{ width: 200, height: 44 }}
    onPress={async () => {
      try {
        const credential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
          requestedScopes: [
            AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
            AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL,
          ],
        });

        console.log('signed in', credential);
        await signInWithApple(credential);
        // signed in
      } catch (e) {
        if (e.code === 'ERR_CANCELED') {
          console.log('cancelled');
          // handle that the user canceled the sign-in flow
        } else {
          console.log('apple authentication error', e);
          // handle other errors
        }
      }
    }}
  />
);

export default AppleAuthenticationButton;
```

```js
export const signInWithApple = async (credentials) => {
  const {
    identityToken, user, email, authorizationCode, fullName,
  } = credentials;

  apiCall('users/sign_in', 'post', {
    method: 'apple',
    identityToken,
    user,
    email,
    authorizationCode,
    fullName,
  });
};
```

Also, as I noted in my comment below I found that there are 2 keys provided with the apple credentials and only one of them works. I have no idea why, but the following code works better than the code linked in the earlier response.

```rb
  def validate_apple_id

    name = params[:name]
    userIdentity = params[:user]
    jwt = params[:identityToken]

    begin
      header_segment = JSON.parse(Base64.decode64(jwt.split(".").first))
      alg = header_segment["alg"]

      apple_response = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(APPLE_PEM_URL))
      apple_certificate = JSON.parse(apple_response)
      token_data = nil

      apple_certificate["keys"].each do | key |
        keyHash = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(key)
        jwk = JWT::JWK.import(keyHash)
        token_data ||= JWT.decode(jwt, jwk.public_key, true, {algorithm: alg})[0] rescue nil
      end

      if token_data&.has_key?("sub") && token_data.has_key?("email") && userIdentity == token_data["sub"]
        yield
      else
        # TODO: Render error to app
      end
    rescue StandardError => e
      # TODO: Render error to app
    end

  end
```

Comment: Hi @David Hersey, could you please tell me what gems do you need to make your code run? (For example gem jwt, gem doorkeeper etc)