# How to validate an ID token signature with apple as an alternative to google oauth2

Tags: php, ios, oauth-2.0, apple-sign-in

Hello all i have created with google oauth api an easy way to validate an ID token signature for debugging by using  the tokeninfo endpoint.

To validate an ID token using the tokeninfo endpoint, i make an HTTPS POST or GET request to the endpoint, and pass my ID token in the id_token parameter. For example, to validate the token "XYZ123", make the following GET request:

https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123

If the token is properly signed and has the appropriate values I got an HTTP 200 response (i follow this guide https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

What is the alternative choice within apple? Any recommendations on how to fix the exact same thing for apple?

Here is an example of my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
              CURLOPT_URL => 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=' . $request->input('token'),
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $responseDecoded = json_decode($response);

            if (isset($responseDecoded->error)) //FAILED TO GOOGLE AUTHENTICATED
            {
                if ($responseDecoded->error=='invalid_token')
                {
                    return response()->json(['status' => 'fail', 'message'=>'invalid_token']);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

A key thing to understand here:

- There are a myriad of ways for users to sign in - one of them is Apple - they come and go - see the [Curity Authenticators Page](https://curity.io/product/authentication-service/) to get a feel for this.
- Protecting your data should work the same in all cases.

So if you base your data protection around Apple it will just not work for people who do not use Apple to sign in and you are restricting your possibilities.

Here is how the solution should work:

- Your UIs and APIs talk to an Authorization Server (AS)
- The AS manages the connection to Apple and the 25 other possible authentication methods
- Every time you add a new authentication option, zero code needs to change in any of your UIs and APIs
- Your UI and API code remains simple and portable over time

To summarize, I would recommend your apps talk to Google OAuth2 - which helps to protect your data, whereas Apple should play a smaller role of being an authentication method - Google should talk to Apple for you.

At Curity we provide a [Sign in with Apple](https://curity.io/resources/learn/sign-in-with-apple/) capability. Our main mission is around protecting data though ...

**ID TOKEN VALIDATION**

If this is received in a browser response it should be validated by the app. This usually involves downloading token signing public keys from the Authorization Server. Some providers may give you an endpoint that does this as in the Google case.

Apple provide some (non standard) behavior as in [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user) to do an equivalent thing.

But coding this in your app is likely to lead to further problems later, when you try to implement authorization. Note also that an ID token should not be used to protect data in APIs - use access tokens instead.

Comment: Added some further info - you have not really explained your requirement though - are you trying to authorize requests for data or to verify an assertion (which is what an ID token is) in a UI?

Comment: i am interesting only to verify the token just like the tokeninfo here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint